# Getting data out QFutureWatcher

Tags: c++, qt, qtconcurrent

I am trying to connect my Qt application to a database. Since I have a GUI, of course the only way to do this is in a separate thread. I found out that I can do it via `QtConcurrent::run`. Here is my code:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) {
  // ...
  QFuture<bool> worker = QtConcurrent::run(this, &MainWindow::connectDatabase);
  QFutureWatcher<bool> *watcher = new QFutureWatcher<bool>;
  connect(watcher, &QFutureWatcher<bool>::finished, this, &MainWindow::databaseConnected);
  watcher->setFuture(worker);
}

bool MainWindow::connectDatabase() {
  QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL");
  db.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
  db.setUserName("user");
  db.setPassword("pass");
  db.setDatabaseName("mydb");

  return db.open();
}
```

It works but I am not able (obviously) to get any data out of the process. For example, I would like to know if the connection succeeded and it would be ideal if I could get it through the slot.

I could add the `watcher` as a member of the class and query it from the slot but this approach would be tedious for many async task I believe.

What should I do?

Comment: Can't you emit from `MainWindow::connectDatabase()`

Comment: @drescherjm, the slots affect the UI, one changes the status bar text and the other displays an error message box. According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733142/qwidgetrepaint-recursive-repaint-detected-when-updating-progress-bar), UI changes can only be made from the main thread which will lead to more tedious calls

Comment: @Victor, He means that you just can emit a signal about the connection at the end of the `connectDatabase()` method but not to affect the UI in the method.

Comment: @VladimirBershov yeah, I got that, but won't the signal method be executed on the same separate thread, meaning that I can't change the UI there either?

Comment: I've edited my answer, you can just use `Qt::QueuedConnection`

Comment: `Qt::QueuedConnection` is the key to cross thread signals and slots. Although Qt will select the safe connection mode if you did not specify it anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make `worker` a class member (because the local variable will be deleted on exit from the constructor):

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) {
  // ...
  m_worker = QtConcurrent::run(this, &MainWindow::connectDatabase);
  QFutureWatcher<bool> *watcher = new QFutureWatcher<bool>;
  connect(watcher, &QFutureWatcher<bool>::finished, this, &MainWindow::databaseConnected);
  watcher->setFuture(m_worker);
}
```

Way 2:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) { 
    connect(this, &MainWindow::mySignalAboutDBOpen, 
        this, &MainWindow::databaseConnected, Qt::QueuedConnection); 

        QtConcurrent::run(this, &MainWindow::connectDatabase);
    }

//and in the connectDatabase:
bool MainWindow::connectDatabase() {
    //...
    bool ret = db.open();
    emit mySignalAboutDBOpen(ret);
    return ret;
}
```

Please note that the `QSqlDatabase db` variable also is local and will be deleted on exit of `connectDatabase()`.

See [Qt::ConnectionType](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum)

Comment: It won't be deleted because it's allocated with `new`, or will it?

Comment: @Victor, Yes, `watcher` is allocated, but not the `worker`

Comment: although this does not satisfy me, and it's probably not your fault but how things are made in Qt, I am going to accept this because it provides all the information I asked for. thank you!